# What kind of metal drums are used to store Hydrochloric Acid?

Tags: acid-base, metal, safety, equipment

I would expect Hydrochloric Acid to be stored exclusively in glass or plastic containers, but I was surprised to find Honeywell offers it for sale in 30Kg metal drums ([Link](https://shop-lab-honeywell.com/hydrochloric-acid-30721)).

I think Hydrochloric Acid would dissolve Nickel, Chromium and Iron in stainless steel, which leaves me wondering what kind of metal that could be, and whether this form of storage wouldn't (at least slightly) contaminate the acid?

Answer (score 4):

We might as well consult the experts, namely storage tank manufacturers.  [This site](https://www.protank.com/hydrochloric-acid) describes several types of storage tanks, none of them metal except for rubber-lined steel, in which (we hope) the rubber keeps the acid out of contact with the steel.  Rubber lining of steel is often used in processes such as acid rinsing tanks where the steel is needed for structural purposes, but for a storage tank as such the referenced site renders cross-linked polyethylene better.

Comment: It's interesting (and nice in a way) to see natural rubber still being used for such applications nowadays, though I'm not sure how they deal with quality consistency using such natural products for sensitive applications. Do you think that the acid in the 30Kg drum will have the exact same quality as that in the glass bottles? Or is the acid in the glass bottles coming from a drum anyways?

Comment: @Hans - given that the HCl was likely bulk-shipped in a railcar (steel with a rubber lining, see http://www.gatx.com/wps/wcm/connect/GATX/GATX_SITE/Home/Rail+North+America/Products/Equipment+Types/Tank/Acid+and+Specialty/Acid/), likely the bottles and drums were both filled from bulk storage at a distribution facility.